# StringBuilder - setLength(0) vs new instantiate, what is better?

Tags: java, android, performance, stringbuilder

i have a loop (repeated 2 times every iteration when i'm received data from Bluetooth), and i'm using `StringBuilder` for append the data separate and on final process i need **clear the StringBuilder obj**,

I'm using now new instantiate, but, i already used `.setLength` method, which is better than `.setLength` or new instantiate?

Example of code that receive data from Bluetooth device:

```java
 private void receive(byte[] data) {
     peso.append(new String(data));
     receiveText.setText(peso.toString().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "")+" Kg"); 
     // int i = Integer.parseInt(peso.toString().replaceAll(("\\r|\\n"), ""));
     Log.i("Val of append actual", String.valueOf(peso));

     if(peso.length() >= 3) 
         peso = new StringBuilder();

 }
```

Other details:
I know the max size for my "peso", this is can help on the choice?

Comment: Can you share your piece of code in which you are doing this, for clarity.

Comment: You're unlikely to to see any significant difference. Keeping the variable in a small scope and creating a new object would work just fine and not provide any surprises. Using `setLength(0)` won't give you any performance advantages, but your code may end up looking "weirder".

Comment: You can [edit] your post and add a [mcve].

Comment: The OP clearly knows *how*, which the duplicates addressed. This question is about whether it matters which way it's done (which it most likely doesn't).

Comment: Sorry, i added code now, thanks all!

Comment: If a performance is so critical it's better to to use `setLength(0)`, but looking on your code there are other expensive operations like `replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)"` and string concatenation `" Kg"`

Comment: It doesn't matter. In your above code, you could do two or three more important optimizations, but they hardly matter either. The blue tooth communication costs much more.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about your use case. But anyhow, new instantiate is always a good option rather than setting length to zero, it shows better intention of code as your code will be more understandable and readable.

**The performance difference is really negligible, but your code will be simpler.**

Comment: *"but your code will be shorter and simpler"*... can you add an example to help me understand how?

Comment: I should have used word "simpler only" but anyhow sb.setLength(0); or sb.delete(0, sb.length()); doesn't depict true intention of code. It is better for readability that we use StringBuilder v = new StringBuilder();

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating can be slow, because creating a new Object takes time, but deletion of content from StringBuilder requires no memory allocation process for its internal array, which makes the process better and faster.

Answer (score 2):

I have even read that `new StringBuilder` was faster in one instance.
So that is more or less an irrelevant micro-optimisation. Profile it in your case.
I would give an initial capacity: `new StringBuilder(64)`.

Remarks:

- Currently `if (peso.length() >= 3)` is probably for testing.
- Specify the Charset of the `data` bytes. Best StandardCharsets.UTF_8.
- Logging is slow; remove it.
- Regex is slow. Below is the non-regex replace.
- \R is for any newline, \n, \r\n, \r, NEL.

So:

```
 private void receive(byte[] data) {
     peso.append(new String(data, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
     String pesoS = peso.toString();
     //receiveText.setText(pesoS.replaceAll("\\R", "")+" Kg");
     receiveText.setText(pesoS.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")+" Kg"); 
     Log.i("Val of append actual", pesoS);

     if (peso.length() >= 3) 
         peso = new StringBuilder(16);
 }
```

Comment: I'll remove Log after the app finalized, this is debug version, thanks for this tips!

Comment: A curiosity, why need specify Charset?

Comment: Without explicit parameter, the default platform encoding is used. For crossplatform data (a file you provide, remote data; net/database) it is guaranteed to create a non-portable (=wrong) application. So that would be smelly code. Even use `Charset.getDefaultCharset()` to clearly indicate you are using local data.

Comment: I'll added UTF-8 because i need receive data from Arduino (with Bluetooth) and i'll send the data to Firebase Database. Thanks

Comment: *"Regex is slow."* In fact, the major overhead is the parsing. Using a preparsed regex is nearly as performant as fixed string search.